# Add a space to a label Programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I have a label and this code:

```
            string User = Environment.UserName;
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "This Software is Licensed to:" + User;
```

For some reason the output is:

```
This Software is Licensed to:UserName
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple fix:

```
string User = Environment.UserName;
toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "This Software is Licensed to: " + User;
// Add a space after 'to:'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: face palm! Wow i feel bad...thanks, i will accept your answer when it will let me

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert a space after the ":"